# Is it possible to use the single resource file for all english cultures?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

So the question is can I point out that my application supports en-US, en-GB and use for all of them the single resource file?

The intention is that I want my application to be available for all english-speaking countries. But it's meaningless to have different translations, because there are no specific translations.

Does it have a sense considering the mentioned intention to point out all those specific cultures in a manifest?

Comment: Since the differences will include changing of formatting for things like Date strings, currency types, etc. What would it hurt to point out the different supported CultureInfo types? Might as well...but not sure that's the answer you're looking for so submitted just as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - just use one English file and make it as default culture. This way even when en-GB is selected, for example, the app will fallback to en-US :)

As for date formatting - just be sure to use CurrentCulture - it gets formatting from the Regional and Number settings (and not CurrentUICulture which is for language needs only). This way people with, say, en-US UI language and Number formatting set to de-DE will still see the app in English but have number formatting as German.

There is a common confusion between CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture and that Language equals formatting. That's why I see many 12-hour formats throughout Windows Phone/Store apps that simply ignore my Regional settings. A must-read regarding confusion about UI and Number formatting: http://forums.asp.net/post/1080435.aspx

Comment: What if my default language is Russian?

Comment: This means that the app will show everywhere in Russian if no resource is found (there are more people knowing English :), so you better change that).

But if you do not want to change the default you need to set default UI locale on App startup to the English one in case you decide that RU is not preferable. Here is how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098643/how-to-set-ui-language-in-code-for-windows-phone-application

Comment: What should be the name of the general english resource file (one for all cultures)?

Comment: I ended up with that the default culture is russian. If I see that a current region is not ru than I set the UI culture to en-US explicitly.

Comment: Only one question remains: if the app declares that it supports en-US, en-GB, but contains only en-US file, can it turned out that it won't pass the market validation?)))

Comment: Not sure about this. Sorry :( Anyway - there are two ways. First is to not list it as "supported" (people will see English in Store, and not Englush (UK)) OR put and empty file (since you will be switching it nevertheless).